# Complex Linq filter query

Tags: sql, linq

I have the following data structure

```
Store
Id
StoreName

Product
Id
Name
StoreId

Category
Id
Name

ProductCategory
Id
ProductId
CategoryId

Deal
Id
Name

DealCategory
Id
DealId
CategoryId
```

My requirement is to get a collection of strings representing categories and then query for stores which have a product or a deal in any of the given categories. Can anyone help as I am stumped. I get the right results if I don't filter by categories but the filter bit just seems to fail s I get no records back and I am certain that there is at least one Store with both a product and a deal in the given categories.

Here is my code so far, if I remove the where clause, I get the right data i.e. all the Stores (that have Deals or Products?! I haven't tested this discrimination yet).

```
from s in ctx.Store
join d in ctx.Deals on s.ID equals d.StoreID
join l in ctx.Products on s.ID equals l.StoreID                        
where d.DealCategories.Any(dc => categoriesList.Contains(dc.Category.Name.ToLower()))
group s by s.ID into sg
select new { Store = sg.FirstOrDefault() };
```

Comment: Show what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Hi thanks, I will post when I get to work tomorrow